# Regex for selecting upto char before char 'x' before char 'y'

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

Want to select text from `first` to `the char before 'x' before 'y'`.
Need to look for `'y'` first then look backward for first occurrence of `'x'` (or last `'x'` in finding) and select upto just before that `'x'`.

Example: (input -> output)

```
abxabxaby -> abxab
```

(upto the first occurrence of `y` is `abxabxaby`. Then upto first backward `x` (or last `x` in finding) is `abxabx` and before `x` is `abxab`)

```
12xabcyabcxay -> 12
```

(upto first occurrence of `y` is `12xabcy`, then first backward `x` is `12x` and before `x` is `12`)

```
abcxy -> abc
```

(Same rule. `abcxy`, then `abcx` so `abc`)

```
abcx -> (No match, as no y)
abcy -> (No match, as no x)
abcyx -> (No match, not in correct order)
```

Comment: Asking for a regex is much the same as asking for someone to write you some code. Please show the results of your research and your own code, and we will gladly help point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^[^y]*(?=x)
```

It finds everything that's not a `y` greedily, until it sees an `x`. The "everything that's not a `y`" part makes sure it finds the first `y` in the string. And the "greedy" part makes sure it finds the *last* `x` before the first `y`.

However, this will not work if the string has no `y`. So you need to check for that separately, simply using `contains("y")`.

Comment: why not just use a lookbehind?

Comment: @Michael Can you explain what you mean? Also, if you have a solution, why not post it as an answer?

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper. As of now there is no possibility of not 'y' so this will work fine but if I find more specific solution I'll update. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try Regex: `^(?=.*y)([^y]*)(?=x(?=[^x]*y))`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vSXqio/1)

Please note that this will also satisfy the requirement `abcx -> (No match, as no y)`